# Maven: Assemble Child Project (module) In Multi Module Project

Tags: java, maven

The following setup:

```
rootpom
 |- parentpom
 |   |- projectApom
 |   |- projectBpom
 |   |- other projects poms
 |- other projects poms
```

Each project in the hierarchy is bound by using <module> tag on its parent pom as well the parent being specified by the <parent> tag.

ProjectA and ProjectB both specify the assembly plugin using the fragment:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>ClassToExecute</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now I go to the directory of the rootpom and execute:

```
mvn --projects parent/projectB compile assembly:single
```

The problem is now that projectB depends on A (and some others) so using this command `assembly:single` will be applied to all the projects.

So the question goes how can I compile multiple projects (dependencies) and only assemble a single one (the last)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: don't use `assembly:single` on the command line but bind an execution of the `maven-assembly-plugin` to a particular phase for the project you want.

If you only want to assemble only project B then in B's POM, you would have:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>ClassToExecute</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This way, running `mvn --projects parent/projectB clean package` will package only B.

Comment: but would it also compile the dependencies as well? The dependencies are not installed in their current version.

Comment: @MartinKersten If they are modules of the same multi-module project, yes it will work.

Comment: I tried and it failed. It told me that a dependency was not found. So it does not recreate depending modules. I am unsure it is because i used: "--projects parentpom/projectApom" which is the project rootpom/parentpom/projectApom and the dependency missing would be rootpom/otherPom. But from the mvn plan it shows that it only wants to build the projectApom other dependencies are as well missing.

Comment: @MartinKersten Why are you using `--projects` to begin with? Why not just simply `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Because i need to select the module / child project I want to build. I do not want to build the complete project tree but only a module of it.

Comment: But you should also build the modules required by B. Use `mvn package -pl projectB -am`. This will also build its dependencies.

Comment: This would also result in applying the package directive to all of the subsequent dependencies. What I am looking for is something like package this project and compile everything else that depends on it

Comment: @MartinKersten You have to do that. Maven starts a lifecycle build for your project. That lifecycle has several phases and all of those phases are applied to the each module. You can't apply one phase to one module but not the others: this is because your multi-module project is a single Maven project and the phases are applied to the project.